# If statement not working properly in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

The If statement i created doesn't work properly. It only works for the first sub  condition of every condition. So say for example Combobox2.text is set to "Running " and Combobox3.Text is set to the value "6mph"`it won't return the value of  CStr(472 / 80 * weight) in TextBox3.Text, but if Combobox2.text is set to "Running " and Combobox3.Text is set to "5mph" (the first condition after`Combobox2.Text = "Running" ) it will work and the value of `CStr(472 / 80 * weight)` is assigned to `TextBox3.Text`. Can someone please help or better still tell me if there's another way of structuring this in order for it to work.

```
If ComboBox2.Text = "Running" Then
        If ComboBox3.Text = "5mph" Then
            wez = CStr(472 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez
        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "6mph" Then
            wez = CStr(590 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez
        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "7mph" Then
            wez = CStr(679 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez

        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "8mph" Then
            wez = CStr(797 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez

        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "9mph" Then
            wez = CStr(885 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez

        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "10mph" Then
            wez = CStr(944 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez
        End If

    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Cycling" Then
        If ComboBox3.Text = "<10mph" Then

            wez = CStr(236 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez

        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "10 - 11.9mph" Then
            wez = CStr(354 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez
        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "12 - 13.9mph" Then
            wez = CStr(472 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez

        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "16 - 20mph" Then
            wez = CStr(590 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez

        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "16 - 20mph" Then
            wez = CStr(708 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez

        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = ">20mph" Then
            wez = CStr(944 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez
        End If

    ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Swimming" Then

        If ComboBox3.Text = "Freestyle, slow" Then

            wez = CStr(413 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez

        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Freestyle, fast" Then
            wez = CStr(590 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez
        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Backstroke" Then
            wez = CStr(413 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez

        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Breaststroke" Then
            wez = CStr(590 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez


        ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Butterfly" Then
            wez = CStr(649 / 80 * weight)
            TextBox3.Text = wez

        End If

    End If
```

Comment: What happens when you perform step-through debugging?

Comment: I think your questions has a typo in it:
For example if Combobox2.text = "Running " and Combobox3.Text ="6mph" it won't return the value of wez = CStr(472 / 80 * weight)   In this case, based on your code, the return value should wez = (Cstr(590 / 80 * weight).  So, your problem statement is actually correct.

Comment: Visual Studio includes a powerful debugger.  Using it, you could have stepped thru that code to find the error (*and* learn a fair mount about how code *actually* executes).   Most of all, you could have the answer in about half the time it took to post the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, you are checking for `ComboBox2.Text` again - inside the second `If..Elseif...End If` statements, except for the first `If` statement.

> ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "6mph" Then

Try this

```
If ComboBox2.Text = "Running" Then
    If ComboBox3.Text = "5mph" Then
        wez = CStr(472 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez
    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "6mph" Then
        wez = CStr(590 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "7mph" Then
        wez = CStr(679 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "8mph" Then
        wez = CStr(797 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "9mph" Then
        wez = CStr(885 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "10mph" Then
        wez = CStr(944 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez
    End If

ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Cycling" Then
    If ComboBox3.Text = "<10mph" Then
        wez = CStr(236 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "10 - 11.9mph" Then
        wez = CStr(354 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "12 - 13.9mph" Then
        wez = CStr(472 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "16 - 20mph" Then
        wez = CStr(590 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "16 - 20mph" Then
        wez = CStr(708 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = ">20mph" Then
        wez = CStr(944 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    End If

ElseIf ComboBox2.Text = "Swimming" Then

    If ComboBox3.Text = "Freestyle, slow" Then
        wez = CStr(413 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "Freestyle, fast" Then
        wez = CStr(590 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "Backstroke" Then
        wez = CStr(413 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "Breaststroke" Then
        wez = CStr(590 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "Butterfly" Then
        wez = CStr(649 / 80 * weight)
        TextBox3.Text = wez

    End If
End If
```